# What is the density of photon energy in intergalactic space?

Tags: radiation, photons, intergalactic-space

What is the average density of photon energy (over all wavelengths) in intergalactic space? In other words, if you took a typical cubic meter of intergalactic space, how much electromagnetic radiation energy would be contained in that cubic meter at any given time?

Comment: Even in interstellar space, most of the photon energy is due to the CMB. There are some relevant numbers here: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/19395/16685

Comment: 2nd result for your 1st paragraph on google... Very in depth info inc. nrg. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/233801/how-many-photons-are-there-in-free-space-on-average

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/233801/how-many-photons-are-there-in-free-space-on-average https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/196366/does-the-number-density-of-photons-n-gamma-approx-108-mathrm-m-3-refer

Comment: We can have fun with this, since lots of photons don't even "fit into"  a m^3  if you take their wavelength into account.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft The fact that photons with λ > 1 m comprise ~0.15% of all photons slightly ruins the fun, though… ;-)

Comment: Hi Mark, do any of the suggested answers answer your question? I think [this discussion on the total energy of photons per volume](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/19395/5264) is what you're after, but you may also find [this discussion on the number density of photons](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/196373/70207) interesting.

Comment: Hi Pela, yes, the suggested answers address my question quite well.  Thanks!

Comment: Great, I'll vote to close this one, then. We aim to have as few duplicates as possible. The phrase in the comment below "Does this answer your question?" is a standard automatic text, not because I didn't hear you :)